# How to get XHRs content in iOS as safari web inspector does

Tags: ios, xmlhttprequest, afnetworking

When I use Safari Web Inspector I get a folder named **XHRs** and it has some JSON files.

Is there a way to get these files in my iOS using `AFNetworking`?

Answer (score 0):

No, AFNetworking is not a tool for monitoring what websites do.

You could use UIWebView's delegate method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` to see what a website loads, and parse it out yourself.

If you're looking for reporting on your own app, you could alternatively use a service like [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/mobile-monitoring) instead of building your own thing.